# Type 4 Driver Issue - Multiple SQLs (Compound SQL)

Tags: jdbc, db2, weblogic

I have a query with multiple calls in the same line(see code below)

The Statement object is automatically created by JDBCTemplate.

The JDBCTemplate is instantiated as new JDBCTemplate() and the datasource is looked up from the weblogic server pool.

class A implements org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCallback {

```
public Object doInStatement(Statement stmt) throws Exception {

String sql = "select * from a where pk = 'test';select * from b where pk = 'test';select * from c where pk = 'test'";

Statement stmt = 

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

rs = stmt.getResultSet();
...
rs = stmt.getMoreResults();
...
rs = stmt.getMoreResults();
...
```

}

Using IBM's Type 2 driver, the above worked perfectly fine. We had to change the driver to Oracle's Type 4 JDBC driver and when we did that, the above broke. It does not work anymore and I get the error below:

> [DAO.exec] ERROR :
>   java.sql.SQLException: [OWLS][DB2 JDBC Driver][DB2]ILLEGAL SYMBOL
>   select * from a where pk ; VALID SYMBOLS ARE BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT

Does anyone know why a Type 4 driver would not support the above? Is there a different delimeter I need to use in the statement, different way to make it work?

Note: THis code worked without any problems with the IBM type 2 JDBC driver, it failed when we switched to Oracle's Type 4 driver.

We use weblogic as the application server and DB2 database.

Comment: The error message in your question appears to be missing, can you edit your post to add it?

Comment: `ResultSet` does not have a `getMoreResults` method, `Statement` does.

Comment: Thanks Will and Glenn. Please see the updated question.

Comment: I think you need to show the `Statement` creation. Is it a `CallableStatement`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to execute multiple statements separately not compounded into one string. Most drivers will only allow a single statement to be executed. There are only a few drivers which allow multiple statements to be executed in on statement/execute.

In general you should not depend on this behavior, as it is not explicitly defined in the JDBC spec. If you read between the lines of the JDBC spec, then IMHO executing multiple statements in on statement/execute should not be supported at all, but that is debatable.

Why drivers don't support this: some database systems simply don't support preparing, executing and retrieving results of multiple statements in one statement/execute. So to support it, the driver would actually need to jump through all kinds of hoops to get it to work, even though it is not a requirement of JDBC (or IMHO: not allowed by JDBC).

To substantiate my claim that only one statement should be executed in a single statement/execute:

- *The object used for executing **a** static SQL statement* (from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html )
- *In some (uncommon) situations, **a single** SQL statement may return multiple result sets and/or update counts* http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#execute(java.lang.String)
- Similarly, the JDBC spec always talks about '***a*** query' when talking about statements